# Firebase Multiple Projects iOS Messaging Delegate

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

An iOS app has to use two firebase projects. I was super confused when I realized that the order of configuring the `FirebaseApp` seems to affect the messaging instance obtained by Messaging.messaging().

When I initialize the secondary app first, the Messaging delegate seems only to register registration token changes in the main app at `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)`

```
FirebaseApp.configure(name: AppDelegate.firebase_main_app_name, options: login_app_options)
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = SOME DELEGATE OBJECT
```

But when I register the main app first, the messaging delegate seems to respond to only registration token changes in the secondary app.

When I register the main app first and
retrieve the FCM token by calling `messaging_instance.retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID: AppDelegate.gcm_sender_id)`

The token retrieved is different from the one from `Messaging.messaging().fcmToken`

But if I register the secondary app first then the two FCM tokens are the same.

The main firebase app can only send notification if I register the secondary app first.

I'm super confused by all this as this behavior isn't documented anywhere. What if I want to receive notifications from both firebase projects? Is there a way to tell which firebase project Messaing.messaging.delegate would reply to? Also, why does the order of configuring the two Firebase apps make a difference?

Comment: i've the same problem too, tried to load secondary plist but i receive just push from one project

Comment: Same issue here and seems to be same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801656/in-ios-swift-app-registration-of-a-second-firebase-app-cant-receive-remote-n